# r - How to set xlim and ylim range in a highcharter plot?

Tags: r, plot, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to set a specific range in my highcharter axes plot

```
 library(highcharter) 
 h <- highchart() %>% 
      hc_title(text = "Scatter chart with size and color") %>% 
      hc_add_series_scatter(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg) %>% 
      hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
h
```

The current result: [scatter with range = c(5, 40) at xlim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQfA0.jpg)

The desired plot: [scatter with range = c(5, 35) at ylim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V21lx.png)

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: A search for highcharter found this http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max. So in your case `%>% hc_yAxis(max = 35)`

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks Pierre

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Pierre Lafortune commented, the answer is:

```
%>% hc_yAxis(max = 35)
```